# SinglePage navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

My website uses onePageNav and scrollTo jquery code. I would like to insert code which correct my position on the website when i click on the same link in the navigation (i scroll mouse up or down but current button (hover) in navigation has not moved yet on to the next one).

OnePageNav code:

```
;
(function ($, window, document, undefined) {

    // our plugin constructor
    var OnePageNav = function (elem, options) {
        this.elem = elem;
        this.$elem = $(elem);
        this.options = options;
        this.metadata = this.$elem.data('plugin-options');
        this.$nav = this.$elem.find('a');
        this.$win = $(window);
        this.sections = {};
        this.didScroll = false;
        this.$doc = $(document);
        this.docHeight = this.$doc.height();
    };

    // the plugin prototype
    OnePageNav.prototype = {
        defaults: {
            currentClass: 'current',
            changeHash: true,
            easing: 'swing',
            filter: '',
            scrollSpeed: 750,
            scrollOffset: 0,
            scrollThreshold: 0.5,
            begin: false,
            end: false,
            scrollChange: false
        },

        init: function () {
            var self = this;

            // Introduce defaults that can be extended either
            // globally or using an object literal.
            self.config = $.extend({}, self.defaults, self.options, self.metadata);

            //Filter any links out of the nav
            if (self.config.filter !== '') {
                self.$nav = self.$nav.filter(self.config.filter);
            }

            //Handle clicks on the nav
            self.$nav.on('click.onePageNav', $.proxy(self.handleClick, self));

            //Get the section positions
            self.getPositions();

            //Handle scroll changes
            self.bindInterval();

            //Update the positions on resize too
            self.$win.on('resize.onePageNav', $.proxy(self.getPositions, self));

            return this;
        },

        adjustNav: function (self, $parent) {
            self.$elem.find('.' + self.config.currentClass).removeClass(self.config.currentClass);
            $parent.addClass(self.config.currentClass);
        },

        bindInterval: function () {
            var self = this;
            var docHeight;

            self.$win.on('scroll.onePageNav', function () {
                self.didScroll = true;
            });

            self.t = setInterval(function () {
                docHeight = self.$doc.height();

                //If it was scrolled
                if (self.didScroll) {
                    self.didScroll = false;
                    self.scrollChange();
                }

                //If the document height changes
                if (docHeight !== self.docHeight) {
                    self.docHeight = docHeight;
                    self.getPositions();
                }
            }, 250);
        },

        getHash: function ($link) {
            return $link.attr('href').split('#')[1];
        },

        getPositions: function () {
            var self = this;
            var linkHref;
            var topPos;
            var $target;

            self.$nav.each(function () {
                linkHref = self.getHash($(this));
                $target = $('#' + linkHref);

                if ($target.length) {
                    topPos = $target.offset().top;
                    self.sections[linkHref] = Math.round(topPos) - self.config.scrollOffset;
                }
            });
        },

        getSection: function (windowPos) {
            var returnValue = null;
            var windowHeight = Math.round(this.$win.height() * this.config.scrollThreshold);

            for (var section in this.sections) {
                if ((this.sections[section] - windowHeight) < windowPos) {
                    returnValue = section;
                }
            }

            return returnValue;
        },

        handleClick: function (e) {
            var self = this;
            var $link = $(e.currentTarget);
            var $parent = $link.parent();
            var newLoc = '#' + self.getHash($link);

            if (!$parent.hasClass(self.config.currentClass)) {
                //Start callback
                if (self.config.begin) {
                    self.config.begin();
                }

                //Change the highlighted nav item
                self.adjustNav(self, $parent);

                //Removing the auto-adjust on scroll
                self.unbindInterval();

                //Scroll to the correct position
                $.scrollTo(newLoc, self.config.scrollSpeed, {
                    axis: 'y',
                    easing: self.config.easing,
                    offset: {
                        top: -self.config.scrollOffset
                    },
                    onAfter: function () {
                        //Do we need to change the hash?
                        if (self.config.changeHash) {
                            window.location.hash = newLoc;
                        }

                        //Add the auto-adjust on scroll back in
                        self.bindInterval();

                        //End callback
                        if (self.config.end) {
                            self.config.end();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            e.preventDefault();
        },

        scrollChange: function () {
            var windowTop = this.$win.scrollTop();
            var position = this.getSection(windowTop);
            var $parent;

            //If the position is set
            if (position !== null) {
                $parent = this.$elem.find('a[href$="#' + position + '"]').parent();

                //If it's not already the current section
                if (!$parent.hasClass(this.config.currentClass)) {
                    //Change the highlighted nav item
                    this.adjustNav(this, $parent);

                    //If there is a scrollChange callback
                    if (this.config.scrollChange) {
                        this.config.scrollChange($parent);
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        unbindInterval: function () {
            clearInterval(this.t);
            this.$win.unbind('scroll.onePageNav');
        }
    };

    OnePageNav.defaults = OnePageNav.prototype.defaults;

    $.fn.onePageNav = function (options) {
        return this.each(function () {
            new OnePageNav(this, options).init();
        });
    };

})(jQuery, window, document);


$(function () { // this is the shorthand for document.ready
    $(window).scroll(function () { // this is the scroll event for the document

        scrolltop = $(window).scrollTop(); // by this we get the value of the scrolltop ie how much scroll has been don by user
        if (parseInt(scrolltop) >= 80) // check if the scroll value is equal to the top of navigation
        {
            $("#navbar").css({
                "position": "fixed",
                "top": "0"
            }); // is yes then make the position fixed to top 0
        } else {
            $("#navbar").css({
                "position": "absolute",
                "top": "80px"
            }); // if no then make the position to absolute and set it to 80
        }
    }); //here
}); //here
```